# How to make this snow writing text effect with python libs

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

[snow writing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz6F4.jpg)

i want to use python libs to make this snow writing effect,but do not now how to add noise to text,need help e

I try to use imagemagick but it does not works

```
  magick -size 320x100 xc:lightblue -font Candice -pointsize 72 \
           -fill black     -annotate +24+64 'Anthony' \
           -fill white     -annotate +26+66 'Anthony' \
           -fill lightblue -annotate +25+65 'Anthony' \
           font_stamp.jpg
```

this can draw shadow around text but can not add noise

Comment: Please, share output you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using Imagemagick, since you tried that, I assume that would be OK.

*Python would be harder. But you can always call Imagemagick from Python (or try to convert this in Python Wand, which uses Imagemagick). If you need it in Python/OpenCV, I could take a stab at it. Let me know.*

- Create a random noise image, select one channel, then blur and apply -level to get the brightness reasonable
- Then add your text using -annotate so it can be at an angle and save as MPR: image
- Then read the MPR: image, negate it, and apply -shade
- Then do -compose blend to mix the noise and text images
- Then create a gaussian noise image, select one channel, apply -level and then use morphology convolve to make the noise specks bigger
- Then composite (plus) the previous and current images, blur, auto-level and apply +level-colors to colorize appropriately to match your example.
- Save the result

Unix syntax:

```
convert -size 600x500 xc: -seed 3 -virtual-pixel tile +noise random \
-channel g -separate +channel -blur 0x10 -level 40x53% +write t0.png \
-fill black -pointsize 92 -font arial-bold -gravity center \
-annotate -10x-10+0+0 "Hello\nWinterland\!" +write t1.png +write mpr:txt \
\( mpr:txt -negate -shade 180x60 +write t2.png \) \
-set option:compose:args 80,20 -compose blend -composite -compose over \
\( -size 600x500 xc:black +noise gaussian -channel g -separate +channel \
-level 5x60% -morphology convolve disk:1 +write t3.png \) \
-compose plus -composite \
-blur 0x2.5 -auto-level +level-colors "#273260,#ffffff" \
result.png
```

[image]

Comment: `@Jack Lion` If you need it in Python/OpenCV, I could take a stab at it. Let me know.